# How do I update my ARCore to the version 1.12.0?

Tags: android, augmented-reality, arcore, sceneform

I'm learning Augmented Reality with ARCore in Android Studio. I tried to follow along with a YouTube tutorial and even after doing everything as instructed, my App is crashing when I try to open it.

In the Logcat, I got these error messages:

```
2021-05-27 00:07:27.689 25976-25976/com.example.basicone E/Filament: Panic
    in void *filament::CircularBuffer::alloc(size_t):127
    reason: couldn't allocate 6144 KiB of memory for the command buffer
2021-05-27 00:07:27.689 25976-25976/com.example.basicone A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE) in tid 25976 (xample.basicone), pid 25976 (xample.basicone)
```

I was searching online for the solutions and saw a GitHub Issues page: https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-runtime-toolkit-android/issues/143
where it's mentioned to update to ARCore 1.12.0 to solve the filament errors.

I was wondering how do I do that? Can update ARCore to the newest version fix the issue? If yes, then how do I do that?

Following is my Code:

**MainActivity.java**

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.ar.core.Anchor;
import com.google.ar.sceneform.AnchorNode;
import com.google.ar.sceneform.rendering.ModelRenderable;
import com.google.ar.sceneform.ux.ArFragment;
import com.google.ar.sceneform.ux.TransformableNode;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ArFragment arFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        arFragment = (ArFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.arFragment);

        arFragment.setOnTapArPlaneListener((hitResult, plane, motionEvent) -> {
            Anchor anchor = hitResult.createAnchor();

            ModelRenderable.builder()
                    .setSource(this, Uri.parse("jeep_model.sfb"))
                    .build()
                    .thenAccept(modelRenderable -> addModelToScene(anchor, modelRenderable))
                    .exceptionally(throwable -> {
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                        builder.setMessage(throwable.getMessage())
                                .show();
                        return null;
                    });
        });
    }

    private void addModelToScene(Anchor anchor, ModelRenderable modelRenderable) {
        AnchorNode anchorNode = new AnchorNode(anchor);
//        AnchorNode automatically positions real world space based on anchor
        TransformableNode transformableNode = new TransformableNode(arFragment.getTransformationSystem());
        transformableNode.setParent(anchorNode);
        transformableNode.setRenderable(modelRenderable);
        arFragment.getArSceneView()
                .getScene()
                .addChild(anchorNode);
//        Always the parent should be passed

        transformableNode.select();
    }
}
```

**build.gradle(Module: app)**

```
dependencies {
...
   implementation 'com.google.ar.sceneform.ux:sceneform-ux:1.5.1'
}
```

**Manifest**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.ar" android:required="true" />

<meta-data android:name="com.google.ar.core" android:value="required" />
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in .sfb file support. Android Studio used sceneform plugin to convert models to .sfb format. This plugin is not supported anymore, you can downgrade your Android studio to 3.4 or 3.2, I believe. Or just use gltf file format and the new sceneform version

Comment: I'm using Android Studio 3.5 and Sceneform is supposed to work fine. Because, there's no issue from Sceneform's side in one of my other projects.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, you're absolutely right. Manually updating your ARCore to version 1.12.0 fixes the issue of Filament panicking. I remember that issue in 2019. Download [ARCore SDK for Android v1.12.0](https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk/releases/tag/v1.12.0) and setup it following the [instructions](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/enable-arcore).

**P.S.** Not sure if such an update is possible through UI of Android Studio, due to deprecation of Sceneform and non-supported early versions of ARCore. But you should try.